# how does g++ linking order matter?

Tags: opencv, gcc, compiler-errors, g++, raspberry-pi

I am making a program on raspberry pi and it uses opencv and mysql. they both compile fine when I compile them separately. but after i combine the 2 files I cannot compile them.
I could compile my opencv part using

```
g++  $(pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv)  cv.cpp -o cv -I/home/pi/git/robidouille/raspicam_cv -L/home/pi/git/robidouille/raspicam_cv -lraspicamcv -L/home/pi/git/raspberrypi/userland/build/lib -lmmal_core -lmmal -l mmal_util -lvcos -lbcm_host
```

without any problem and compile my mysql part using

```
g++ -w sql.cpp $(mysql_config --cflags) $(mysql_config --libs)
```

but after  I merge the code and try to compile the merged code using

```
g++  $(pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv)  merged.cpp -o merged $(mysql_config --cflags) $(mysql_config --libs) -I/home/pi/git/robidouille/raspicam_cv -L/home/pi/git/robidouille/raspicam_cv -lraspicamcv -L/home/pi/git/raspberrypi/userland/build/lib -lmmal_core -lmmal -l mmal_util -lvcos -lbcm_host
```

I get an error saying error: ‘conn’ does not name a type
here is my code for that section

```
MYSQL *conn;
conn = mysql_init(NULL); //error here
```

Comment: You need to compile each source file separately with the `-c` flag and whatever package-specific set of flags appropriate for that file. Then link the resulting object files together. The mode you are using now combines compilation and linking in one step. It is only suitable for very small and simple programs.

Comment: so I have to separated them?

Comment: `I merged them. so they are in the same file now` --- this is not a valid mode of work with source code. Please don't.